# Why do pageviews not show up in GTM debugging like every other event?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Here is what it looks like in GTM debugger when you load a page, then make a click.

[image]

However, the odd thing is, here are the page view events:

[image]

The 3rd option down is "Page view", but when I use debugger and perform what I would think is a page view, that event doesn't actually show.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

That trigger fires on Container Loaded event. Also known as event: "gtm.js" in the DL. Well, yes, there's a discrepancy in names between GTM UI and the debugger. It's not a surprise though. There are many more problems with the debugger really. As with GTM. As with lots of other Google services. But it's not too bad overall.

If you want to know more about what page view is, here: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679319?hl=en